# What do the expressions AL CHET or VIDUI mean?

Tags: words

I would like to know what the expressions AL CHET or VIDUI mean, in English please.

Comment: I've edited the title and contents so that other readers will get the correct intent. See the answer, below, also, which explains the pronunciation as well as the meanings of the 2 terms.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are referring to Al Chet (על חטא)that is called [Vidui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confession_(Judaism))

Al Chet means "on Account of this sin" which is a prelude to Vidui - Confession of one's sins, in more detail ie. Al Chet- on Account of the sin of haughtiness.

This features prominently on the Jewish day of atonement of Yom Kippur.